# Prevent prettier-standard from removing semicolons in Typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript, prettier, prettier-standard

I have this Typescript interface definition.

```
interface CurrencyAmountProps {
  value: number;
  currency: string;
}
```

I am currently using `prettier-standard` this command to format Typescript files

`"format": "prettier-standard --parser typescript --write --trailing-comma=all",`

The problem with formatting is that `prettier-standard` removes the semicolons after the `value` and `currency` lines.

This is valid Typescript but it is causing some issue when I try to use `react-intl-cra` to extract formatted messages.

How can I make an exception for not removing semicolons in interfaces in `prettier-standard`?

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to try tslint's "ignore-interfaces", depending on your setup: from the [docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/)

```
"semicolon": [true, "never", "ignore-interfaces"]
```

Comment: This will also cause prettier not to add semicolons if there aren't already one, so I wouldn't consider it a full solution.